# Find a file containg a string in its name using Python

Tags: python

I have a sheet in excel which contains the names of files. I have a folder which contains the files in jpg. The file names in the excel sheet are not complete file names but a part of the full name of the file. I have to search for the file name from the folder and seperate those matching files to a new folder.
Please guide me how can i achieve this target.

Comment: Please edit your question, clarify what your desired output and supply an example dataset (your excel file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for part of the file name in a folder by looking through each element filename in the folder and see if string contains substring:

```
import os

directory = r'C:\Users\admin'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if substring in filename:
        print(filename)
```

You didn't ask how to iterate through elements of an excel sheet, but this can be done via read csv file or a xlsx reader package in python and just put another loop outside the one above for each element. For every file, just store in a list rather than print.